# How to launch parallel coroutines and return result

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to write a function that runs 2 operations asynchronously and returns a result using Kotlin coroutines. For example, I want my `getData` method to run my two `longRunningOperationX` methods at roughly the same time so I get my combined result faster:

```kotlin
fun getData(): String {
  val stringOne = longRunningStringOperationOne()
  val stringTwo = longRunningStringOperationTwo()
  return stringOne + stringTwo
}
```

In Kotlin, I can run these operation using the `launch` and `async` methods.

```kotlin
fun getData(): String {
  GlobalScope.launch { 
    val stringOne = async { longRunningStringOperationOne() }
    val stringTwo = async { longRunningStringOperationTwo() }
    println("result: $stringOne + $stringTwo")
    // return "result: $stringOne + $stringTwo" <- not allowed
  }
  return "?"
}
```

However, as you can probably tell, the result of the operations in the Coroutine scope isn't accessible outside the `GlobalScope`, so my method just has to return what it has at the time, before my long-running operations complete.

So, given this problem space - a non-suspending (not a kotlin `suspend fun`) function that returns a result - how can I run two long-running operations asynchronously (in parallel) but wait for their result before returning using Kotlin coroutines?

Comment: you can wait and return some result from the non suspend function using the `runBlocking` function, but it will block the thread in which it is called. You can't have non suspend function waiting for the result of a coroutine without blocking the current thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use [Structured Concurrency](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952) instead of Global Scope, and `await()` the Jobs returned by `async`.  One way to do so would be like this:

```
fun getData(): String {
  return runBlocking { 
    val stringOne = async { longRunningStringOperationOne() }
    val stringTwo = async { longRunningStringOperationTwo() }
    "result: ${stringOne.await()} + ${stringTwo.await()}")  // will be the return value of the runBlocking lambda
  }
}
```